# HttpURLConnection return response like DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android, http, response, httpurlconnection

I've an old code that execute an http request with DefaultHttpClient and I'm trying to convert it to HttpURLConnection but I'm having troubles with the response.

Here is the original code:

```
private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            return response.getEntity().getContent();
        }
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL url;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(serviceUrl);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + serviceUrl);
    }

    try {

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.connect();
        //Don't know what to do now to return the response(?)
    }
```

But I don't know how to do it to get the same result as with the response.

Comment: Use `conn.getInputStream()`

Comment: you want a method to **obtain** the response?

Comment: @Enzokie ok, thnks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader ISreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(ISreader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            build.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
return build.toString();
```

In this code, you are getting the `InputStream` from the `HttpUrlConnection`, which is used to get the response using `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Ok, thnks.
That sure will help me next time, but now I only needed the imput stream.

Comment: No problem. Please accept this answer if this has answered your question